# How to unit test just one function, without browser, on Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine

Let's say I have a function that performs a very long calculation:

```
export const veryLongCalculation = () => 1 + 1;
```

How can I unit test this function in Angular *without* opening Karma and *without* configuring anything else?

I would like to write a test like this one:

```
describe('Difficult Calculations', () => {
  it('should calculate', () => {
    const calcul = veryLongCalculation();
    expect(calcul).toBe(2);
  });
})
```

If I run `ng test` it starts Karma and the browser (and takes ages).

Can I run just that test *without* opening a browser and initializing everything? I guess there should be a command to do it, already configured. How?

Comment: There isn't a command to do it already configured. Angular CLI's configuration is for testing a front end app and Karma is a browser-based test runner.

Comment: So, if I want to test a simple function, I have to configure jasmine (or anything else) from scratch?

Comment: Yes, your use case is not covered by the CLI's default setup.

Comment: Try to avoid use of karma runner.  The reason is karma uses a real browser for running the tests and jest uses the favourite command line to run its tests. The tests that took 4–5 minutes on KARMA only takes about 1–2 minutes on jest.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest trying Chrome in headless mode. This way Karma and Chrome remain, but the browser window won't be opened and the process will be quicker.

To test it add a script to `package.json`:

```
"test-headless": "ng test --watch=false --browsers=ChromeHeadless"
```

And run it using `npm run test-headless`.

Note that an Angular-based code runs in a browser, so it is highly recommended to run the test suits in a browser. Otherwise, the tests could have false positive/negative results.

Comment: Thanks, I already use it on headless mode, however, it's takes time. I will test actions with ts-node then, and forget this kind of unittest until the front is developed.